# CKAN API key rotation

Tags: ckan

I'm wondering if there are any CKAN extensions that manage API key rotation? We ideally want to rotate API keys for all users every 30 days. I can't seem to find anything in the extensions or community support pages on Stackoverflow or GitHub.
How are other organisations managing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow.

There are none that I'm aware of that handle automatic API key rotation for users. However, writing such an extension is trivial. You can use CKAN's [background workers](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/background-tasks.html) to periodically create a new key:

`result = get_action('user_generate_apikey')(context, {'id': '<id of the user>'})`

I'd also suggest notifying them that their key has been changed, since randomly changing keys would drive me insane.